# How to pass a POST variable without a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

What is the best way to use a PHP table to hold comments from multiple different sections, and be able to distinguish between each different comments section? Is there some way to pass POST data without the need of a form?

Is there some way for me to distinguish between these two forms? Should I be using Javascript and distinguishing by the id of the forms, or is there a cleaner way?

```
<form action="SubmitComment.php" method="post" id="comments1">
    <h3>Name:</h3><input type="text" name="name" cols="100">
    <h3>Comment:</h3><input type="text" name="comment" cols="100">
    <textarea rows=4 cols="100" placeholder="Enter text here!"></textarea>
    <?php $_POST['section'] = 1; ?>
</form>

<!-- I want to be able to distinguish between these two forms. -->

<form action="SubmitComment.php" method="post" id="comments2">
    <h3>Name:</h3><input type="text" name="name" cols="100">
    <h3>Comment:</h3><input type="text" name="comment" cols="100">
    <textarea rows=4 cols="100" placeholder="Enter text here!"></textarea>
    <?php $_POST['section'] = 2; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Ajax (XMLHTTPRequest) can send data without using a HTML form.. Only problem that you need a HTTP form and input if you want to ask information from the user

Comment: most common way when you use two forms on one page and or submit to one `.php` file you add a `<input type="hidden" value="<form_id>" />` to the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to distinguish forms using

`<input type="submit" name="form" value="form1">`

to send data, in that way you can read `$_POST['form']` value and check what form it is

If you want to send data without form you can use ajax with Javascript.

Comment: *"If you want to send data without form you can use ajax with javascript"* Yes but you would still need a form with inputs to ask information.

Comment: I mean, you can use input without `<form>` and without standard form methods

Comment: *"I mean, you can use input without <form> and without standard form methods"* that is invalid html, and you will have to ask yourself how browsers will handle that case and styling with css and javascript handling most likely it will work because most browsers are designed to display invalid html or fix broken/invalid html

Comment: @RaymondNijland - is it your intention to claim that the `<form>` element is the only one that accepts "phrasing content"? If this is not the case, your assertion that the html resultant from pavelbere's suggestion would be invalid appears incorrect. As stated at MDN, any element permitted to accept phrasing content can legally be the parent of an `<input>` element. Forms are no longer a requirement. ;) Buttons too, need only be parented by something capable of holding "prasing content"

Comment: yes that direction i was going @enhzflep well then it seams that W3C HTML 5 specs have loosed up that, because it was first required you placed the input tag in a form tag before it was valid html, iam pretty sure of that.